# VBA: Complex VLOOKUP function (two-column match vertically, one-row match horizontally). Advice on method

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I'm looking for advice on how to approach a certain problem.

In short, I have a matrix with two descriptive columns to the left (Y-axis) and a range of durations/time periods on the X-axis. The first column include bond types, and the second currency. There are 6 kinds of bonds, and 4 currencies. Every combination can have one of four durations.

The problem is that I recieve the mentioned matrix weekly, and the number of rows is different each time because only non-blank rows are reported. Roughly half of them are blank (no activity since last week)

Comment: Even if I can discern what your data look like, it's still not clear what you're asking for.

Comment: As @Marc said, you've told us what data you have, but not what you are trying to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a vLookup() formula for this. A simple SumProduct() formula will help you :) See the Snapshot for an example

**FORMULA**

`=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A15="AAA")*(B2:B15="Dollar")*(C2:F15))`

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

Do let me know if this is not what you wanted?

HTH

Sid

Answer (score 0):

To find a value in Excel based on both a column and row value, you will need to use both a vlookup and a match function.

> =VLOOKUP($A10,$A$1:$E$6,MATCH($B10,$A$1:$E$1,0),0)

Have a look at the example picture below.

![Example for Lookup & Match Formula][1]

http://pzy.be/v/2/LookupMatch.jpg

B@@la